# Windows 10: Find out the exact reason for an unresponsive application

Tags: windows, performance, debug, utilization

I am recently facing randomly unresponsive applications. I would like to exactly pinpoint / debug the reason that causes the application to hang.

CPU utilization is low, memory usage is normal. So I assume it must be some kind of I/O wait, but how can I find out for sure?

**EDIT**:
One characteristic behavior is that almost any application randomly freezes entirely (Chrome tabs, explorer views, image viewers etc.) sometimes for minutes and other applications continue to run normally.

**EDIT2**:
It turns out that it is related to BitDefender anti virus. When I switch off anti virus, the PC runs normally. However, that still doesn't explain why/how BitDefender slows the applications.

Comment: What do the logs say? SSD or spinning rust?

Comment: You'll need to review the BitDefender logs to find out. General FYI: there's no reason to run third-party antivirus on Win10+, as Windows Defender scores on par with top third-party AVs.